# Grails 2.4.5 cache static resources in memory

Tags: caching, grails, grails-2.0

We have a significant load on our grails servers. I'm using lsof to show open files and I'm seeing multiple open file handles for each of our css and js files. We have very few such files, so I think it would make a lot more sense to just cache them in memory and avoid going to the OS for them (avoiding kernel/fs/file handle overhead even if the OS caches them).

Is there some configuration for asset pipeline or something (another plugin?) that will tell it to cache these files in memory and not request them from disk?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of asset-pipeline plugin do you use?
There was an issue with caching of assets in https: https://github.com/bertramdev/grails-asset-pipeline/issues/368

We've fixed this by updating the asset-pipepline dependencies to a newer version in your application.

Or do you have a lot of unique visitors?

Comment: That appears to be about the cache header to the browser. I'm talking about caching on the server, not the browser. Yes, we have a lot of unique visitors. I want to cache the contents of the file in memory and deliver directly from the webapp and not go to the filesystem for those contents.

Comment: @ttt worth looking at memcached too - you can run it with various technologies

Comment: If I wanted a more complex separate solution, it would be to frontend grails with a web server or CDN. But I just want a simple solution of caching the files in grails. I had expected there to be a setting or plugin for this, but... maybe not.